# chmod sudoers without using sudo

Tags: ubuntu, grub, livecd, lubuntu

I have lubuntu installed with persistance on a large usb flash drive, and somehow, My `/etc/sudoers` file has file permissions 0664, when ever I try to use sudo, it says :

> `sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0644, should be 0440`
>
> `sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting`

when I try `chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers` it says:

> chmod: changing permissions of `/etc/sudoers': Operation not permitted

`sudo chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers` causes the first message. Am I using chmod incorrectly? How can I fix this? If you need to know, it is lubuntu 10.10, isntalled with unetbootin.

**EDIT:
I know how to fix it with recovery mode, i just need to know how to get into recovery mode in a live cd, is it possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods:

- Early in the boot process, escape to the bootloader menu, and append the following to the kernel command-line:

  ```
  single
  ```

  **For Ubuntu, this will cause it to boot in the "recovery" mode,** straight into a root shell.

  If chmod in the recovery console complains about a read-only filesystem, remount it read-only:

  ```
  mount / -o remount,rw
  ```

  If `single` doesn't work for some reason, another option is to skip the init process entirely, but this might not enable the persistent overlay.

  ```
  init=/bin/sh rw
  ```

  (deleting any existing `ro` options)
- Alternatively, use another Linux computer which you have root access on – such as a real [live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) (whether it's Ubuntu or not doesn't matter). Then plug in your drive, `mount` the filesystem which has `etc/sudoers` on it (with `-o loop` if necessary), and use `sudo chmod`.

---

> Am I using chmod incorrectly?

The usage is correct, it's just that only the file's owner can change its permissions, and `/etc/sudoers` is normally owned by root – which you aren't.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if recent Ubuntus have root user enabled by default, but you could try

```
su root
```

to get a root shell instead. If that doesn't work, [this guide](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo) takes you through repairing sudo on Ubuntu (I haven't tried it myself!)

Comment: su root asks for a password, is that my password or the root password? ubuntu has a root account, but it has no password, and livecd ubuntu's account password ("") does not work. i will look at the guide

Comment: It sounds like that would work, but how do i get recovery mode on the live cd?

Comment: @invisible: The live CD *itself* is a form of "recovery mode" in that it bypasses the system's auth settings. While using the live CD, you can just use `sudo -s` or `sudo chmod`.

Comment: @grawity `sudo chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers` yields: 

`sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0644, should be 0440`

`sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting`
I am booting from the live cd, i have no ubuntu on my computer.

Comment: @invisible: It seems that you/we confused "live CD" with your USB-installed system. What you can do is boot a [*real* live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) and proceed with recovery from there.

Comment: @grawity no, i couldn't. no (working) cd drive. what i have is a live cd ISO burned to a flash drive, with the persistent file on the flash drive

Answer (score 1):

I think I have sorted it out using this command

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

I can now do

```
sudo -s
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Is this a good enough solution to the problem?

Comment: This will work..it worked for me

Comment: I got `Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory`